# Copy the first cell of column and copy into a new column in front of each row and loop through after blank

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have data in an excel sheet with a name on the top and below is the date in the same column. The next columns are some numbers that I want to add with respect to the name on the top and date.

What I needed is just to copy that name in front of each row, so I can use formulas. There are hundreds of rows with blanks after a total of every name.

10_xxxxxxxxxx_150858
04/01/2019      5
04/04/2019      6
04/05/2019      3
04/07/2019      2
04/08/2019      1

Comment: Please upload an image with the desirable output.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a screenshot and a bit more details on the need would be useful but I think you  can achieve what you want by using the '$'.
When you extend a formula it allows indicating which part of the formula should stay unchanged.

Example:

```
=$A1
```

If you extend this formula to the right, it will always refer to column A.
If you extend it down, the line number will increase but refer to column A is fixed.
In your case, something as follow could be useful:

```
=$A$1
```

Comment: I tried didn't find any option to post a screen shot. Yes but there are thousands of line, and its a different name after each blank.